# How to read a combination list by bash/shell?

Tags: bash, shell, loops, combinations

I have an *A_1* folder, an *A_2* folder, an *A_3* folder.....until *A_561* folders.

Each folder has a sub-directory with a *B_1*, a *B_2*, a *B_3*... and a *B_34* folder.

In the *B_1* folder, there are files named  *F_1_1.txt*, *F_1_2.txt*... *F_1_38.txt*. *F_2_1.txt*, *F_2_1.txt*... *F_2_38.txt*.

In the *B_2* folder, there are files named  *F_1_1.txt*, *F_1_2.txt*... *F_1_38.txt*. *F_2_1.txt*, *F_2_1.txt*... *F_2_38.txt*.

In the *B_2* folder, there are files named  *F_1_1.txt*, *F_1_2.txt*... *F_1_38.txt*. *F_2_1.txt*, *F_2_1.txt*... *F_2_38.txt*.

Then I will run a `java` program to process these files:

```
java -jar beagle.28Sep18.793.jar  \
gt=/A_1/B_1/F_1_1.txt /A_1/B_1/F_2_1 out=/C/test_1.out;.....     

java -jar beagle.28Sep18.793.jar  \
gt=/A_1/B_2/F_1_2.txt /A_1/B_2/F_3_2 out=/C/test_2.out;.....    

java -jar beagle.28Sep18.793.jar  \
gt=/A_2/B_3/F_3_1.txt /A_2/B_3/F_4_1 out=/C/test_3.out;    

java -jar beagle.28Sep18.793.jar  \
gt=/A_3/B_1/F_1_38.txt /A_3/B_1/F_1_38 out=/C/test_4.out;
```

I can run a `for` loop bash to read the files by

```
for folder in $(seq 561); do 
    for file in $(seq 1 34); do 
        for sample in $(seq 1 38); do   
java -jar beagle.28Sep18.793.jar gt=/A_"$folder"/B_"$file"/F_"$file"_"sample".txt /A_"$folder"/B_"$file"/F_"$file"_"sample" out=/C/test_"file"_"$sample".out  
        done  
     done  
done
```

This command can run very slow. I know some files did not exit but the `java` will skip it and run next. I would like to know for this case, how can I write a command to read files correctly.

Comment: Indent your code.

Comment: Do you mean "exit" or "exist"?

Comment: Why not use globbing (wildcards) or `find` rather than constructing the filenames?  At least you won't get any false hits.  The nested loops run slowly *even without calling a program* - 724812 iterations!  You might also consider writing this in Java instead.  Consider:  for every iteration you have (how many?) you will load the java runtime into the machine - that will take ages, I'm not surprised it is slow.  724812 child processes and loads of the java runtime.

Comment: What do you do with the `sample` in the loop `for sample in`?

Comment: Please specify whether `java -jar beagle.28Sep18.793.jar  gt=/A_1/B_1/F_1_1.txt /A_1/B_1/F_2_1 out=/C/test_1.out` is a *single `java` command*, or if not, whether it's a `java` command followed by two shell script assignments, or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't be sure to have understood your question correctly because it is so poorly formatted, but I think you want to run a Java program on each text file in a folder hierarchy. I think you can do that relatively easily and fast in parallel with **GNU Parallel**.

So here's how to generate a list of the text files with `find`:

```
find . -name \*.txt -print
```

If that looks correct, you can run the same again but null-terminate each name and pass it into **GNU Parallel** like this:

```
find . -name \*.txt -print0 | parallel -0
```

Now you want to run a Java program for each file and use an incrementing number for the output file, so we can do a dry-run, which only prints what it would do without actually doing anything, like this:

```
find . -name \*.txt -print0 | parallel -0 --dry-run java -jar beagle.28Sep18.793.jar gt={} out=/C/test_{#}.out
```

If that looks correct, remove the `--dry-run` and run it again and it will run as many instances of Java in parallel as you have CPU cores and keep them all busy till the jobs are done.